# Table of contents appendices in article class

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I followed the following example, my problem with it is that I use article as documentclass and thus the appendices won´t show in my table of contents with their alphabetical order, e.g. A, B, ... it only shows the name appendices.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First section}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
  \chapter{First appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}

  \chapter{Second appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

What I want is to have the alphabetical order in my table of contents like shown here for example [image]

Mine without the alphabetical order:
[image]

Comment: In `article`, appendices are `\section`s and not `\chapter`s. Not sure if that's the problem since you don't show us what you tried,

Comment: I know, when I used \section it didn´t showed in the table of contents. Mine is just looking like this at the end of contents (edited in original post)

Comment: Do you still have `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` in your code? That should be `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}` for `article`.

Comment: That fixxed it for me thank you so much :)